# ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for pyheif , OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty

Tags: python, macos, pyheif

I got problems, when running `pip install pyheif`

This is the end of error output

```
      OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: '/private/var/folders/72/j143y0dd7c109ybb09nzkqhr0000gn/T/pip-install-tibk8tj4/pyheif_79fc191d7c36425faa0f08f88eb5ebb3/.eggs/cffi-1.16.0-py3.11-macosx-10.9-universal2.egg/cffi-1.16.0.dist-info' -> '/private/var/folders/72/j143y0dd7c109ybb09nzkqhr0000gn/T/pip-install-tibk8tj4/pyheif_79fc191d7c36425faa0f08f88eb5ebb3/.eggs/cffi-1.16.0-py3.11-macosx-10.9-universal2.egg/EGG-INFO'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for pyheif
Failed to build pyheif
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyheif, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

What should be done to fix it?

MacOs M1, Python 3.11